# Is inter-app communication possible without using URL Scheme in iOS?

Tags: ios, app-store, url-scheme

I want to open App A from App B, but App A is already in the appstore without configuring a [custom URL Scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1). From App B how can I communicate with App A?

Comment: there is the only way to Upload new version of App A with that URL scheme. Then only i am able to communicate with between two apps ryt??  @DavidBerry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, It's not possible.

You need to re-upload your previous application with URL schema.

FYI, **App Extension** is another way, If that suits to your app requirement.

Refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/) for detail information.

Answer (score 0):

[This Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW2) lists two ways to do inter-app communication locally. One is through AirDrop and the other is through a custom URL scheme. Only the latter can launch another app.